# How to use zend framework components

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to php zend framework. And i want to implement php in my ERP project . ERP project is for diamond ring.

I have tried to create simple project using user-guide from Zend.frameword `http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/index.html`

And I am going to use zend framework 2.1

I want to start with user register ,user roles and right .

I checked the zend_permission and zend_session. But i am not clear about how to start this.

Can anyone tell me how to start.

Also refer any tutorial for user permissions, session, database adaptor and zend_ajax

Comment: This isn't really the right place to ask this question. This site is intended for specific questions or problems you have with your code, not general discussion and How To guides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, slow down.

You have declared you are going to use Zend Framework 2.1 and then proceeded to ask questions about Zend framework 1.x. (class names with underscores are ZF1, Zf2 is PHP5 namespaced)

Using Zend Framework 1 is not trivial to learn and Zend Framework 2 is worse.

For ZF1 start with http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/ and http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.html

You can use the same sites for their ZF2 tutorials but you'll probably need something more, like [Web Development with Zend Framework 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A9Y4HLU). (this is the only ZF2 book I've found so far)

Typically to use specific components it's simplest to implement an autoloader for the Zend framework library you want to use. It's not always easy to sort out all of the dependencies, although ZF2 is better about that then ZF1 is.

Comment: Ya i got it . can u tell me which version in zend is better for erp and saas . And also for implementing the user right and roles

Comment: There is no "Better" or "Worse" with Zend Framework. It usually ends up being "This is what we use." Either version is appropriate to almost any kind of project. That being said, if you are just starting out, learn ZF1 for now. There are far more resources available to assist in learning.

Comment: ok . so i can start the project using zf1 after getting idea about zf1  , right ?